# How to reduce the size of style.chunk.css in next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I am working on a Web App that uses next.js (^9.1.1) with @zeit/next-less (^1.0.1). I am trying to improve the performance of this App. I am using LightHouse to measure the performance.

The LightHouse opportunity section is showing this -

[image: LightHouse opportunity Section]

The coverage section of chrome dev tools is showing that 97.5% of the CSS in styles.chunk.css file is unused, I think this is because it contains CSS of almost all the pages of my Next App -

[image: Coverage section of chrome dev tools]

I have two questions:
1. What does this styles.chunk.css file do?
2. How can I decrease the size of this file in a way that it only contains styles that are needed for that particular page?

I have tried using next-purgecss, but purgecss is only working in development mode and not working in production mode, my config file written down below -

```
module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    withLess(withPurgeCss({
      purgeCssEnabled: ({ dev, isServer }) => (!dev && !isServer),
      cssModules: true,
      cssLoaderOptions: {
        getLocalIdent: (loaderContext, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
          const fileName = path.basename(loaderContext.resourcePath);
          const shoudTransform = canBeTransformed(loaderContext.resourcePath);

          if (!shoudTransform) {
            return localName;
          }
          const name = fileName.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, '');
          return `${name}___${localName}`;
        },
      },
    })),
    // withBundleAnalyzer({}),
  ],
  nextConfig,
);
```

Comment: Were you able to get this working with CSS Modules? My styles are not applying because purgeCss module don't recognize the CSS Modules

Answer (score 2):

You can use `next-purgecss` plugin

#### Installation

```
npm install @zeit/next-css next-purgecss --save-dev
```

Note: `next-purgecss` requires one of the following css next plugins:

- next-css
- next-less
- next-sass

#### Edit next.config.js

```
// next.config.js
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css')
const withPurgeCss = require('next-purgecss')

module.exports = withCss(withPurgeCss())
```

**By default, `next-purgecss` will always remove unused CSS, regardless of build environment.**

Edit:

#### For Production

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = withCss(
  withPurgeCss({
    // Only enable PurgeCSS for client-side production builds
    purgeCssEnabled: ({ dev, isServer }) => (!dev && !isServer) 
  })
)
```

More info here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-purgecss

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. purgeCSS is working fine in development mode but in production mode, the styles are not applying. How can we fix that?

Comment: I've added the configs for production

Comment: I am doing the same but the styles are still not adding in the production build. I am using next-less with cssModules flag set to true.

Comment: When I run "next start" no styles are applied.

Comment: I have added my config file in the question.

Comment: I went from `79MB` to `9.2MB`. Beautiful